# AngularJS: Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

So after watching some tutorials I created my first test app, but for some reason it is not working.
The goal of the app is to get product info out of a json file and put it in a ng-repeat.

My HTML code:
http://pastebin.com/fa9iLHim

My AngularJS code:
http://pastebin.com/GJKzAwWZ

My JSON data:
http://pastebin.com/yRXPzf7D

My folders:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tWE2.jpg

```js
var app = angular.module('TrialerApp', []);

app.service('trialerProducts', function($http, $q) {
  /*var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('/resources/json/data.json').then(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });*/

  this.getProducts = function() {
    /*return deferred.promise;*/ // stubbing response as we don't have access to backend
    return $q.when([{
      "name": "Crunchyroll",
      "description": "A TV browsing thing"
    }, {
      "name": "Febreze",
      "description": "Clean things up"
    }, {
      "name": "Minecraft",
      "description": "A nice and fun game"
    }, {
      "name": "Door",
      "description": "You'd better walk through this.."
    }, {
      "name": "Window",
      "description": "An invisible wall!"
    }])
  }
});

app.controller('TrialerCtrl', function($scope, trialerProducts) {
  var promise = trialerProducts.getProducts();
  promise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.players = response;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<div class="mainContainer" ng-app="TrialerApp">
  <h1>Trialer Products</h1>
  <div ng-controller="TrialerCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
          <td>{{player.name}}</td>
          <td>{{player.description}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think it's somewhere a mistake with linking my files etc. but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) of it instead of linking to pastebin. That will make it alot easier to help out!

Comment: I have voted to close this question as off topic for the following reason: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: I created a plunk based on your data, and it seems to me as if it's working fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/i11nxSRy07C6n2kVpktx?p=preview

EDIT: Forgot to mention, there was a syntax error in your JS file, an extra parenthesis at the end of line 6 (`$http.get('/resources/json/data.json').then(function (data))`) which I removed. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: I too have done the same.

Comment: Come on, this guy create 3 pastbin and one screenshot to try his best to provide the more sources, and he is downvoted to death? That's not the way to greet new comers.

Comment: I agree with Cyril. The guy is new, cut him some slack. point him towards Plunker as a better way of showing his code than PasteBin, and help him with his issue. SO is here to offer help, not make people feel bad for not having written a perfect question.

Comment: Plunkr as we can put code in snippet and run it here?

Comment: I voted for re-open, as there is now a code snippet in the question, which was the original reason for putting on hold.  However, I'm still not sure what the question is, since the code snippet actually runs correctly and returns the correct results in the question?

Answer (score 1):

No error message, it is hard to say.

Possible problems :

HTML : Missing the closing brace on this line (not a problem for some browser, a big problem for other, it depends):

```
KO <div class="mainContainer" ng-app="TrialerApp"
OK <div class="mainContainer" ng-app="TrialerApp">
```

Javascript : Too many parenthesis (a big problem for all browser)

```
KO $http.get('/resources/json/data.json').then(function (data))
OK $http.get('/resources/json/data.json').then(function (data)
```